# Visualforce Page redirect not working in apex class constructor

Tags: visualforce, controller, redirect, parameters

In visualforce page URL, i have one parameter 'id'. In apex controller class, i have written code in constructor like below:

```
public myconstructor(){ 
   String ObjId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
    if(ObjId !=NULL && ObjId != '')
    {
       // get object details
    }else{
       redirectToAnother();
    }
   } 
    public PageReference redirectToAnother() {
             PageReference page1= Page.myPage; 
             page1.setRedirect(true);
             return page1;
     }
```

If 'Id' parameter exist and not NULL, then i am getting object data. But, if 'id' does not exists, then page not redirect to another page.

Any one have any ideas on this. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using constructor to redirect the User, you can use page-action to redirect based on the criteria.

So, the code looks like

```
   <apex:page controller="myconstructor" action="{!redirectToAnother}">

   public myconstructor(){ 
       String ObjId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
       if(ObjId !=NULL && ObjId != '')
       {
           // get object details
       }
   } 
   public PageReference redirectToAnother() {
        String ObjId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
        if(ObjId == NULL || ObjId == '')
             PageReference page1= Page.myPage; 
             page1.setRedirect(true);
             return page1;
        }
        return null;
     }
```

Comment: But this action method not working for sites< please help on this.